# Multiple dynamic LinkButton avoid postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have many `LinkButton` but I want it to have single`OnClick` event to all `LinkButton` since it will do the same thing (and I will just get the value of `CommandArgument`). My problem is that LinkButton keeps on doing postback which will refresh the page every time I click on a LinkButton.

I tried many solutions such us adding `href="#"`, using `OnClientClick=""` property on the LinkButton control in asp.net, but what happens is it doesn't trigger the ClickEvent anymore.

Is there other way to achieve this? Or javascript is my only way in solving this problem?

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelLinkButton" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
   <triggers>
       <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="LinkButton6" EventName="Click" />
   </triggers>
 <contenttemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton6" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-info" OnClick="lnkAddToGroup_Click"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></asp:LinkButton>
 </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Do you need LinkButton? Or you can use simply <a> tag?

Comment: yes linkbutton is required

Comment: Are LinkButtons in a repeater or GridView?

Comment: I don't get what you mean of in a repeater, I'm in a designing phase, i didn't do the coding yet, coz it's easy, but the linkbutton will be inside a table and will be added through code behind using StringBuilder. Don't get mad

Comment: You are in a designing phase but you talk about LinkButton (and not hyperlink): so i talk about Repeater. It's a .net control that help you to build, for example a table (as you told) avoiding to concatenate strings. I can't understand how you can add LinkButton using StringBuilder. Maybe you are creating source code files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using an UpdatePanel like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="u1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="lnt" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:LinkButton ID="lnt" runat="server" onclick="LinkTest_Clkk">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: in my code behind? i will still use the LinkTest_Click event? because I also read using update panel but I don't know how to properly use it

Comment: Yes in Code Behind, Yes you can still use Click event and role of that Update panel is it wont do a full postback

Comment: hmmm it doesn't trigger my click event?. and by the way, you need to add <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager> for this

Comment: @JCBorlagdan it should , can you paste you code to the question

Comment: When i click it, it doesn't immediately udpates the content, but when i refresh the page, thats the only time it updates

Comment: @JCBorlagdan where is the content is being updated? i mean which control?

Comment: I'm testing it out on a textbox first.. so it's simply textbox1.Text = "something"... this one is inside the lnkAddToGroup_Click event

Comment: @JCBorlagdan move that Textbox to the `ContentTemplate` to reflect the updated vale

Comment: I almost got it, What is did is to place everything inside the update panel, since placing the textbox inside the content template will destroy the design.. but not the only problem is my div but very much thanks